# Finding all the possible LCS

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was thinking about Longest common sub sequence problem using dynamic programming.

Not able to figure out a way how to print all lcs.

One way i can think of create a graph out of the table and find all the possible paths in that graph but that solution seems very slow.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: is there any better way? @poorvank_bhatia

Answer (score 1):

How about building  a TRIE tree that includes all the sub sequences. While building it, also hold in each node a list of the original sequences that have that specific sub sequence.

Once you have accomplished this, it is simply a matter of finding all nodes in the tree who have a list containing all original sequences. (Just add a counter and check that)